# PHP Sqlsrv Pagination

Tags: php, sql, pagination, sqlsrv

I am having an issue where I am doing a query and it is coming back with about 30 pages, I was hoping to have it come back with 1,2,3...,30 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,etc. please see below for code that I have used:

```
function getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage)
{
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
$rows = array();
$i = 0;
while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC, 
     SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE,         $offset + $i)) && $i < $rowsPerPage)
{
    array_push($rows, $row);
    $i++;
}
return $rows;
}

// Set the number of rows to be returned on a page.
$rowsPerPage = 30;

// Connect to the server.
$serverName = 'test';
$connOptions = array("Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connOptions);
if (!$conn)
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

//  Define and execute the query.  
// Note that the query is executed with a "scrollable" cursor.
$sql = "select * from info";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
if ( !$stmt )
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

// Display the selected page of data.
echo "<table border='1px' align='center'>";
$pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? $_GET['pageNum'] : 1;
$page = getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage);

foreach($page as $row)
echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
<table align='center'>
<?php
// Get the total number of rows returned by the query.
// Display links to "pages" of rows.
$rowsReturned = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
if($rowsReturned === false)
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
elseif($rowsReturned == 0)
{
echo "No rows returned.";
exit();
}
else
{     
// Display page links.
$numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage);
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
{
    $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
    print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
echo "<br/><br/>";
} 



sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the code review stack exchange since people can comment on your code there and suggest improvements: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have added this question to the suggested forum, but have been notified that it is not fit the site.

Comment: yeah I saw that it has been put on hold there but I believe there might be other questions like this here or on code review stack exchange. You just need to search for it.

Comment: see if this helps: http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/ you might need to customize that code to your needs though.

Comment: Maximus2012, thanks for your help I really appreciate it, unfortunately the link you send me to has been written for mysql but I am using sqlsrv and many different syntax between the two as we cannot use "LIMIT x, y "in sql query and I am unsure of alternative for this, the code i am using now is actually from "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/01/26/paging-data-with-the-sql-server-drivers-for-php-simplified.aspx" , hopefully I can find something with sqlsrv. @Maximus2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have went on Code Review and JohnMark13 helped me to find a solution for this problem:

```
// Display page links.
$numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage);
$renderedEllipses = false;
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
{
    //If you always want to render pages 1 - 3
    if($i < 4) {
        //render link
        $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
        print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }

    //If you always want to render current page number
    else if($i == $pageNum) {
        //render link
        $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
        print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        //reset ellipses
        $renderedEllipses = false;
    }

    //if you always want the last page number
    else if ($i == $numOfPages - 1) {
        //render link
        $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
        print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }

    //make sure you only do this once per ellipses group
    else {
         if (!$renderedEllipses){
             print("...");
             $renderedEllipses = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Thanks @JohnMark13

Comment: Guys, I am having issues with this code but not the same issues, its more with searching, was unsure whether too open another question or continue in this as its the same code, can someone please advise :)  - @JohnMark13